# CSS Moving Floating Element to another position

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress based website using WooCommerce and a plugin called Extra Product Options. With this plugin, other than having extra options, I get a floating box in the lower left corner displaying selected options.

[Link to product page](https://www.fonster24.tk/produkt/tra-vridfonster/)

Is it possible through CSS to move the floating box from the lower left corner to be fixed beneath the product images?

The current position workes perfectly except when someone with a smaller screen is using it, as which point the floating box covers some of the other product images and the information displayed at the buttom.

If this is overly complicated is there any other recommended solution to this problem? All advice is very appriciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in the css find .tm-floating-box and set the position from fixed to relative

This is what you have

```
.tm-floating-box {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("../images/p5.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

This is what you want to change it to

```
.tm-floating-box {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("../images/p5.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

It may not put it under the image but it will stop it from flowing around and stick it to the left.

Comment: Strange. It actually disappeared completely when I did that.

Comment: It may have moved right to the bottom.. scroll and check. If you need it after the images you need to edit the HTML and that may be something that WooCommerce controls in Wordpress.